# Extra argument 'predicate' in call in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
   print(searchBar.text!)

   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)

   request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]

   loadItems(with: request, predicate: predicate)
}
```

The error is "Extra argument 'predicate' in call". 
And if I remove the predicate argument, then the search in the array of items does not happen.
This is in a table view. 
You can view the full code at [GitHub](https://github.com/HarshitRuwali/Todoey-iOS13/blob/master/Todoey/Controller/TodoListViewController.swift) at the very end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the predicate to the request

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
   print(searchBar.text!)

   request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)

   request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]

   loadItems(with: request)
}
```

Comment: This does not throws the error but the searching is happening.

Comment: The answer is correct. You have to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` at the end of `loadItems`